# How to override the NetworkManager in Unet properly?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unet

I need some customization on the NetworkManager Class for my game I'm working on. I've read, that it's pretty common to override stuff from the NetworkManager. So I've implemented the NetworkManager as CustomNetworkManager class like this :

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class CustomNetworkManager : NetworkManager
{

}
```

I hope I'm right, that I don't have to implement a method to get all the functionality from the base class?

I duplicated my NetworkManager Object, which basically was just the NetworkManager with another CustomNetworking Script. Then I replaced the old NetworkManager with my new CustomNetworkManager and changed the references in the other script accordingly.

So my old GameObject looks like this :

[image]

And this is my new GameObject :

[image]

The old GameObject works (I just have to change the NetworkManager type in my CustomNetworking class)

But the new GameObject with the custom implementation is getting the following error :

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
CustomNetworking.EnableMatchmaker () (at Assets/CustomNetworking.cs:27)
```

The CustomNetworking class with the error looks like this :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.Networking.Match;
using UnityEngine.Networking.Types;

public class CustomNetworking : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CustomNetworkManager manager;
    public MatchInfo currentMatch;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        manager = GetComponent<CustomNetworkManager>();
    }

    public void EnableMatchmaker()
    {
        manager.StartMatchMaker(); //This is the first call which is made and where the error occurs
    }

    public void CreateMatchmakerMatch()
    {
        manager.StartMatchMaker();
        manager.matchMaker.CreateMatch(
            manager.matchName,
            manager.matchSize,
            true, "", "", "", 0, 0,
            manager.OnMatchCreate);


    }

    public void FindMatchmakerMatch()
    {
        manager.matchMaker.ListMatches(0, 20, "", false, 0, 0, manager.OnMatchList);

        if (manager.matches != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < manager.matches.Count; i++)
            {
                var match = manager.matches[i];
                manager.matchName = match.name;
                manager.matchMaker.JoinMatch(match.networkId, "", "", "", 0, 0, manager.OnMatchJoined);
            }
        }
    }

    public void DestroyMatchmakerMatch()
    {
        manager.client.Disconnect();
        manager.matchMaker.DropConnection(manager.matchInfo.networkId, manager.matchInfo.nodeId, 0, manager.OnDropConnection);
        manager.matchMaker.DestroyMatch(manager.matchInfo.networkId, 0, manager.OnDestroyMatch);
        manager.StopMatchMaker();
    }

    public void StartMatchmakerMatch()
    {
        //manager.StartClient()
      manager.ServerChangeScene("MainScene");
    }
}
```

I think I did some failure with implementing the overwritten NetworkManager, hopefully someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: Is the project set up correctly to use networking? Check this thread out: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cant-use-matchmaker-on-different-computer.334004/

Comment: Yeah the old network manager does the job I was already able to play via LAN and Internet

Comment: What exact type is 'manager'?

Comment: It's the NetworkManager script from Unet https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.html

Comment: Can you post CustomNetworking.cs?

Comment: Here you go, edited the question for you :)

Comment: I just checked the "manager" variable in my CustomNetworking class for null and it is null. I can't explain why or how to fix it

Comment: Can this just be a simple problem of Unity not being able to find the object it's supposed to? Try dragging CustomNetworkManager into the manager slot in CustomNetworking. If that doesn't work, try running the code in your Start() in Awake() instead. (If you already found a solution, then this is the wake-up poke for an answer :P)

Comment: maybe you didn't use a singleton